# is it possible to store ResultSet from a query into an array and use the array as search parameters for an SQL query

Tags: java, sql, arrays, derby

i have two tables WorkSkillsPlanning(WSP) and TrainingAchieved(TA). WSP hold a list of planed training and targeted number of people to be trained e.g. ISOO:90001 10 people while TA holds the actual number of people trained as well as the actual course done. Since WSP and TA are dynamic in the sense that the data they hold is not static neither is known as training plans can change is it possible to run an intersect query on these table to find similarities i.e a course in WSP which has actually be done and recorded in TA. Store the results of the intersect query in an array e.g. MyArrayList{ISO,COMMUNICATION) these being values present in both table and use MyArrayList values to run count queries on TA to establish the number of people who would have done the course i.e ISO and COMMUNICATION  and use the resultant to subtract from WSP (ISO,COMMUNICATION).

here is an example, first part

```
"Select QUALIFICATIONGROUP from  APP.WSP intersect select COURSEBOOKED from APP.BOOKCOURSE"
```

which results in ISO and COMMUNICATION which i want to store in an ARRAY or variable.

second part

```
select count(COURSEBOOKED) from APP.BOOKCOURSE where COURSEBOOKED = Variable1
 rs.getString(Count(COURSEBOOKED))
 value returned == 5
```

re do the process again for COMMUNICATION and any other course in the array, of which after use the values returned from the count query to subtract to subtract WSP total minus TA total.

I hope this makes sense

as requested the first query is

```
private void updateTable(){
    String sql = "Select QUALIFICATIONGROUP from  APP.WSP intersect select COURSEBOOKED from APP.BOOKCOURSE";
   try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
       PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        //while (rs.next()){
       jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
        //}
   }

   catch (Exception ex) {

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);


   }
```

this will give me data that is in WSP that is also present in AT and display it in a table.

the second query is now supposed to take the first value of Row one in the table and pass it to the second query as below

```
public void tableOne() throws Exception{
    String search = "value of first row from the query ontop";
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(COURSEBOOKED) from APP.BOOKCOURSE where COURSE BOOKED = '"+search+"'";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            sum = rs.getString("COUNT(COURSEBOOKED)");
            txtSum.setText(sum);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
}
```

This query is supposed to run as many times as the rows produced by the first query.

this query select all the data in WSP table.

```
public void tableTwo() throws Exception{
    String sql = "select * from APP.WSP";
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            search= rs.getString("QUALIFICATIONGROUP"); //sets the search string for tableOne();
            next = rs.getInt("TOTALTRAININGPLANNED");
            System.out.println(search);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(next);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
}
```

finally the count values from the second query are used to subtract the values
from the variable next (next= rs.getInt("TOTALTRAININGPLANNED");) generated from the last query and the finally value of next = rs.getInt("TOTALTRAININGPLANNED") - value of the second Count query are stored in an variable which will be used to reveal wether planned training and actual training are equal or different.

I hope i have clarified issues

Comment: To be honest, it didn't for me atleast. I hope for someone else it does.

Comment: I don't think you want to store your intermediate results in a Java array or variable. Rather, you want to phrase your entire query in SQL. I find it useful to build up the sub-queries first: work on expressing your various sub-queries in SQL and test them out. Update your question with the details of those various sub-queries, and we'll show you how to  compose them into a top-level query that finds the WSP records you want.